# CSS Positioning - Auto fill both sides of a div element with tile background

Tags: html, css

I'm making a web page with a header that has an image which is always centered, and I would like to put a tiled background along the X axis on each side but not underneath it because it is semi-transparent. This is the container:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="header_left"></div>
    <div id="header_center"></div>
    <div id="header_right"></div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
    div {
       position: absolute;
    }

    #header {
       height: 166px;
       width: 100%;
       top: 0px;
    }

    #header_left{
       background-image:url('header_piece.png');
       background-repeat:repeat-x;
       height: 166px;
       display: block;
       top: 0px;
       left: 0px;
    }

    #header_center {
       background-color: green;
       height: 166px;
       width: 1200px;
       margin-left: -600px;
       left: 50%;
       top: 0px;
       z-index: 2500;
    }

    #header_right {
       background-image:url('header_piece.png');
       background-repeat:repeat-x;
       height: 166px;
       display: block;
       top: 0px;
       right: 0px;
    }
```

But I cant get it to work. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: What are you getting from this so far?

Comment: Im getting the center piece working fine but the left and righ sides are filling up the rest of the space i cant see them at all

Comment: Where is the image in the header?  Is it after the divs, inside of `header_center` or a background image of the header?

Comment: don't quite get what you mean that the left and right sides are filing up the rest of what space?  maybe you can show us a picture or link to a page?

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish something like this? [Fiddle](http://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/token/Token,%20128x128,%20PNG/Star-Favorites.png)

Comment: Well i did it here is the web page: www.l2btg.com ill upload solution soon :D

Answer (score 1):

This one needs to change your HTML. It puts the left and right DIVs inside the Centre DIV and then uses the css to pull them out to the left and right.

The Center DIV is positioned relative to the Header DIV and centred with margin:auto. The left and right DIVs are positioned absolute to pull then outside the Center DIV. The Header DIV has overflow:hidden so any resulting overflow is hidden.

```
<div id="header">
   <div id="header_center">
      <div id="header_left"></div>

      <div id="header_right"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
   position: absolute;
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 166px;
   width: 100%;
   top: 0px;
   z-index: 2500;
}

#header_left{
   position: absolute;
   background-image:url('header_piece.png');
   background-repeat:repeat-x;
   height: 166px;
   width:100%;
   top: 0px;
   left: -100%;
}

#header_center {
   position: relative;
   background-color: green;
   height: 166px;
   width: 1200px;
   margin:0 auto;
}

#header_right {
   position: absolute;
   background-image:url('header_piece.png');
   background-repeat:repeat-x;
   height: 166px;
   width:100%;
   top: 0px;
   left: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I like this solution - http://jsfiddle.net/VceCD/. If center is less than half the width of the screen then it doesn't quite work. But considering he has his set to 1200px and that would be a pretty narrow center I think he is good. http://jsfiddle.net/VceCD/1

Comment: mrtsherman - for very large pages or small centre DIVs you can set the width of the left & right DIVs to some arbitrary large size say 2000px - you would then have to move them accordingly. The left DIV to left:-2000px,The right DIV is still moved left:100% (or the fixed width of its parent node)

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that instead of having, left/center/right that you actually start with what you don't want - the background going underneath the center. Except use a second div to cover up the center so that the semi-transparent background still works. So something like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/pGYsL/

```
#header { width: 100%; }
#tiledbackground { background: repeat-x; }
#coverupbackground { margin: auto; width: 600px; background: white; }
#header_center { opacity: .5; background: blue; }

<div id="header">
  <div id="tiledbackground">
    <div id="coverupbackground">
      <div id="header_center"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is v2 with some pretty backgrounds included =) - http://jsfiddle.net/pGYsL/1/

Comment: hmm not triend it but looks like the background that covers up the tiled background will be like a white block, the problem would be that under this header there will be some content or when u scroll down the page the header will be on top of some content and will not be transparent

Comment: Oh I see. Bummer. Let me take a look at your three div solution again.

Answer (score 0):

Well try this one out instead. Here are the problems I see in your code.

1. Left and Right Div have no width so they aren't going to show up
2. You are seem to be declaring a bunch of things that you don't need. Like height in every child div and top/left values.
3. I don't know if exactly what you want is possible with css.

http://jsfiddle.net/UvngC/

You can definitely create this by floating your divs left and giving them % widths that add up to 100% or fixed widths that add up to a certain amount. But having the center div fixed width and the left and right using whatever space is leftover doesn't really work. How are the left and right supposed to know that they are the same size? How are they supposed to know to use whatever is left over on the screen? I am sure it is possible, but not with your current layout. I can't think of how off the top of my head.

```
#header {
 height: 166px;
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

#header > div { height: 166px; }

#header_left{
 float: left;
 background-   image:url('http://www.profilerehab.com/twitter/images/small/blue_striped_background_2.jpg');
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 width: 25%;
}

#header_center {
 float: left;
 opacity: .5;
 background-color: green;
 width: 50%;
 margin: auto;
 z-index: 2500;
}

#header_right {
 float: left;
 background-image:url('http://www.profilerehab.com/twitter/images/small/blue_striped_background_2.jpg');
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 width: 25%;
}
```